# How to filter results by rich snippets values?

Tags: google-custom-search

I have some itens available from structured-data testing-tool, like:

- pmr-recipe-recipetype-bolos
- pmr-recipe-totaltime-30
- pmr-recipe-name-chocolate

How can i use this values to filter the results from CSE?
Like, show pages with pmr-recipe-recipetype-bolos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try your search term this way

- more:pagemap:recipe-name:chocolate
- more:pagemap:recipe-totaltime:30
- more:pagemap:recipe:type:bolos

It should return the search result you look for.

Hope this help :)